# How do I run a swing application's executable jar file on a button click in a JSP page?

Tags: java, swing, jsp

i want to run my desktop application's executable jar (swing .jar file) file into my JSP page via a button, when i click on it.

Comment: Nothing to do with JSP. I think you want Java Web Start.

Comment: In addition to the advice of @ElliottFrisch: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application (from a link or button in a web page) is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an applet and do the same.

However, *(as Andrew suggested)* that's no longer a good option is per [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

> With modern browser vendors working to restrict and reduce plugin
>   support in their products, developers of applications that rely on the
>   Java browser plugin need to consider alternative options such as
>   migrating from Java Applets (which rely on a browser plugin) to the
>   plugin-free Java Web Start technology.
>
> Oracle plans to deprecate the Java browser plugin in JDK 9. This
>   technology will be removed from the Oracle JDK and JRE in a future
>   Java SE release.

It's highly likely that whatever you're trying to do with Swing would be possible with HTML, CSS and Js as well.